# Getting HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable error when trying to return an object in Spring REST controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restcontroller, http-error

Here i'm trying to update an object and return the updated object in JSON format in a Spring REST controller.

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/revert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> revertUserData(@RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName) {

    User user = new User();
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();

    try {
        user = userService.findUserByName(userName);
        user.setLastName(null);

        userResponse.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userResponse.setLastName(user.getLastName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(userResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(userResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

UserResponse class :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserResponse {

  @JsonProperty("email")
  private String email;
  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String lastName;

  //getter and setter methids 

}
```

pom file :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error im getting :

```
The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the
user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is
unwilling to supply a default representation.
```

Comment: This indicates a header was not set. You are probably missing `produces` in your `RequestMapping`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513644/http-status-406-not-acceptable-spring-mvc

Comment: couldn't resolve 'produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON' parameter to the controller. only header is there

Answer (score 1):

You mixed JAX-RS and Spring MVC annotations: `@RequestMapping` comes from Spring and `@Produces` from JAX-RS. If you take a look at the `@RequestMapping`'s [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) you'll see that it has a `produces` parameter. So you should have something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/revert", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> revertUserData(@RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName){
...
}
```

Comment: its using Spring 3 version, i dont know if thats why ' produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON' is not resolving

Comment: Take a look here for further configurations: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml